# Flutter: The role of the Inkwell widget and "widgets that support taps"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/ripples

The Inkwell widget is explained on the above page.
I'm not sure when to use the Inkwell widget.
I can understand it somehow.

As a procedure when we want to add a ripple effect

1.Create a widget that supports tap
(Generate a widget that supports taps)

2.Wrap it in an InkWell widget to manage tap callbacks and ripple animations.
(Wrap with Inkwell widget)

In the explanation, the Container widget is used as a "widget that supports tapping" as a sample.

I guess the Container widget is probably a "tap-supporting widget",
What kind of widget is "a widget that supports taps"?
(Requirements for saying that taps are supported)

After all, as for how to use the Inkwell widget,
"If you want to add both to a widget that cannot add ripple effect or tap callback by itself"

Comment: Have you gone through my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in doc https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html, **A rectangular area of a Material that responds to touch.** It doesn't matter which child widget it has, it performs splash animation on it. But The `InkWell` widget must have a `Material` widget as an ancestor.